# A POSIX getdelim() and getline() implementation for MSVC

Tags: c, strings, io, windows, posix

Tired of always having problems in reading arbitrary length lines from file under Windows, I tried to write a POSIX `getdelim()` and `getline()` implementation for MSVC. Let me know if you have any suggestion for improving this:

#### getline.h

```
#ifndef GETLINE_H
#define GETLINE_H

#include <stdio.h>

#define restrict __restrict
typedef long long ssize_t;

ssize_t getline(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n, FILE *restrict stream);
ssize_t getdelim(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n, int delim, FILE *restrict stream);

#endif /* GETLINE_H */
```

#### getline.c

```
#include "getline.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

// MSVC specific implementation
static void fseterr(FILE *fp)
{
    struct file { // Undocumented implementation detail
        unsigned char *_ptr;
        unsigned char *_base;
        int _cnt;
        int _flag;
        int _file;
        int _charbuf;
        int _bufsiz;
    };
    #define _IOERR 0x10

    ((struct file *)fp)->_flag |= _IOERR;
}

ssize_t getdelim(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n, int delim, FILE *restrict stream)
{
    if (lineptr == NULL || n == NULL || stream == NULL || (*lineptr == NULL && *n != 0)) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }
    if (feof(stream) || ferror(stream)) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (*lineptr == NULL) {
        *n = 256;
        *lineptr = malloc(*n);
        if (*lineptr == NULL) {
            fseterr(stream);
            errno = ENOMEM;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    ssize_t nread = 0;
    int c = EOF;
    while (c != delim) {
        c = fgetc(stream);
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        if (nread >= *n - 1) {
            size_t newn = *n * 2;
            char *newptr = realloc(*lineptr, newn);
            if (newptr == NULL) {
                fseterr(stream);
                errno = ENOMEM;
                return -1;
            }
            *lineptr = newptr;
            *n = newn;
        }
        (*lineptr)[nread++] = c;
    }
    if (c == EOF && nread == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    (*lineptr)[nread] = 0;
    return nread;
}

ssize_t getline(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n, FILE *restrict stream)
{
    return getdelim(lineptr, n, '\n', stream);
}
```

Comment: This is just a comment, but POSIX specifies that getdelim/getline set the error indicator for the stream on *any* error, including failure to allocate memory. This simplifies error handling for the caller. Unfortunately, there is no portable way to set the error indicator.

Comment: @JohnScott I didn't know about this. [glibc implementation](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/iogetdelim.c.html#62) doesn't do it. Neither this [freebsd implementation](https://github.com/lattera/freebsd/blob/master/contrib/file/getline.c). Do you have a link to the POSIX specification?

Comment: Here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html: “If an error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, and the function shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the error.”

Comment: @CostantinoGrana You can edit the code in the question if there are no answers.

Comment: @JohnScott Thank you. The edit should address the error indicator thing (MSVC specific). I also update the buffer size only if I manage to allocate memory.

Comment: Could you consider re-licensing this under 2-clause BSD? I'd like to use this in a 2-clause-BSD open source project and not spoil my chances of being included in a Linux or BSD distro right away. The default license here is CC BY-SA and the attribution it requires is a big no-go.

Comment: @JannPoppinga Check the version on [GitHub](https://github.com/CostantinoGrana/msvc_getline).